# how to add context menu in hosted usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a Winform usercontrol and need to use in wpf window.I have hosted the control in wpf window.The control itself does not have any context menu. How can I add context menu in that control from wpf window? WPF code as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875(v=vs.100).aspx  is as below.
Namespaces:

```
      xmlns:gc="clr-namespace:MyUsercontrol;assembly=MyControl"
```

Control code:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">
        <gc:MyControl x:Name="c1">           
        </gc:MyControl>           
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: As I understand from your code, you based your example in this [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF by Using XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875(v=vs.100).aspx) tutorial. If yes, pls edit your question and add this information, if not, give it a look.

Comment: @athafoud actually the link is not related to context menu but i added it.

Comment: Yes I know, but in the steps it has some assembly that you should better ensure that you include.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">
    <gc:MyControl x:Name="c1">
        <gc:MyControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Item 1" ></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </gc:MyControl.ContextMenu>  
    </gc:MyControl>           
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: I already tried this. I get the following exception:
The specified value cannot be assigned.The following type was expedted:"ContextMenu" @Athafoud

Comment: @bill A silly question, but are you sure you are not missing the inner `<ContextMenu>`

Comment: I did not miss. That's why I get the above exception message that "contextmenu type is expected".